# What limit should I get increased

Tags: rest

We are integrating a document management system with Salesforce.com using REST API. We are going to be dealing with lots of REST API calls though out the day to push documents in Salesforce.com. What is the current REST api limit and what exact governor limit should I demand from salesforce support to get increased.

Comment: Sara, I would say wait.   We recently integrated many of our systems and we thought we would be getting into trouble with limits but we are barely even scratching the surface.  We are doing API called ever 15 to 30 minutes for many systems too..

Comment: +1 to what @EricSSH said. I would suggest testing on a developer edition or sandbox (better) organization to see how close to the limits you are getting.

Comment: Sounds logical, of curiosity , is there any separate limit on REST API or is it same as API limit salesforce imposes.

Answer (score 3):

As [documented here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=integrate_api_rate_limiting.htm), There are two limits which are relevant for such integrations.

1. Total number of API calls that are allowed in a org in 24 hours. You can view the current API usage in Setup -> Company Profile
2. Concurrent API calls you can make at same time. There is no right place to view the past history of concurrency api usage but you will get an error when you reach the limit.

Before you try to ask Salesforce to increase the limits, have you done any assessment on which of these limits will be an issue for you?

Comment: why downvote? This information is what OP is looking for.